# Box around circle with intersection

Tags: circles

I want to  create a rectangle Box with three intersected circles:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,positioning,fit,calc,backgrounds}

\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[red] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}
\node (firstcircle)   {};
\node (secondcircle)  {};
\node (thirdcircle)  {};
\draw[name=first] \firstcircle node[below] (A) {$A$};
\draw[name=second] \secondcircle node [above] (B) {$B$};
\draw[name=third] \thirdcircle node [below] (C) {$C$};
\node (box) [fit=(firstcircle)(secondcircle)(thirdcircle), inner sep=1cm,draw,rounded corners] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My Problem is: The rectangle should go around all cirles.

Comment: your question isn't very clear, the code shown produces the error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option 'H'.` and it isn't clear how you want to change the output, which has intersecting circles already.

Comment: The code works fine. But the rectangle ist not aound all circles. It is only in the first circle

Comment: well if that is the question put that in the question:-)

Comment: The problem is that your nodes `(firstcircle)`, `(secondcircle)` etc are just nodes of minimum size at the origin. Add some text to them and you'll see it. You have to make nodes with circle shape to make the `fit` thing work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

I significantly change your code, circle are drawn as nodes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,positioning,fit,calc,backgrounds}

\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=30mm},% C as circle, minimum size is circle diameter
    F/.style = {draw, rounded corners, inner sep=1cm}% F as fit node
                        ]
\node (first)   [C] at (0,0)    {$A$};
\node (second)  [C] at (60:2.1) {$B$};
\node (third)   [C] at ( 0:2.1) {$B$};
\node (box) [F, fit=(first)(second)(third)] {};
\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[red] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @David, glad to hear this. Happy TeX-ing.